# How to find review history

Tags: support, review, flagging

How to find review history? I have some non reason declined flags then I wanted to know how can I find a link to that review?

Comment: You can see an individual user's reviews by looking under the 'all actions' section of their profile and selecting 'reviews;' e.g. [mine](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/296602/t-bongers?tab=activity). You can see the overall history of reviews if you are a 10k+ user (please correct if I'm wrong about the requirement) under the review tab and selecting history - [example](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/review/close/history). I believe that if you have the review privilege, you can see *your* review history under this tab. I don't know what "non reason declined answers" are.

Comment: Do you mean that your answer was deleted?

Comment: @T. Bongers and Arctic Char I wrote answer wrongly I mean flags.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no easy way. If one person agreed with you and left an auto-generated comment, it contains a link to the review. You could also search by hand through recent reviews by numeric ID, I suppose; for example, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/666311) is the most recent LQ review and by decreasing the number you can find recent previous ones. I don't know if there's a better way without being able to see the entire review history, which is a 10k+ privilege.

Comment: There's not much you can learn from the reviews, actually. You flagged [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851511/factorial-proof-by-induction-question) as a duplicate, three reviewers voted to leave open. A few days later the question came to my attention, and I agreed that it was a duplicate. What can you learn from that? That not all people always agree whether something is a duplicate. But you probably already knew that.

Comment: Today, you flagged another question as off topic (missing context, I presume), reviewers disagreed, the question was later closed (as unclear). There's nothing you could learn from the review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find review for a particular post using [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/208490/find-the-reviews-for-a-post?postid=1851511). If the close votes are less than week old, it is possible that they are not in the last [data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data).

---

If you have sufficient reputation, you can see history of recent reviews for each review queue. However, searching through them is rather laborious, it is a reasonable option only for reviews that are not too old.

- [close votes review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/history)
- [reopen votes review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history)
- [suggested edits review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history)
- [low quality posts review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history)
- [late answers review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/history)
- [first posts review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history)

You can find all the above links if you click on [review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review).

---

If you are looking for a post you have reviewed, you can find complete history of your reviews [on your profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews). Similarly, you can find review history of any user on their profile page.